# ebay products in my joomla site

Tags: joomla, ebay

I want show ebay products in my joomla site. Please give me your suggestion Or if any step by step instruction guide. Have any joomla extension provide this ???

Thanks

Comment: Make this a concrete question. What did you try? What problems did you have? Ask about those. If this is just a best-extension question, it does not belong to StackOverflow, see FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of extensions for displaying ebay products: http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=ebay

Comment: Thanks AndreyM! Can we no need any ebay store account to connect with ebay API to show ebay product? Have any idea about this??

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not really familiar with the details but if you wish to display your ebay products/auctions on your website you'll need to have an account there. Maybe some of the extensions allow to show ebay stuff without having an account there (if ebay permits it), but I'm not sure if it makes sense to show some random products/auctions on your website.